# How can I execute a series of commands in a bash subshell as another user using sudo?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

I'm writing a bash script that needs to sudo multiple commands. I can do this:

```
( whoami ; whoami )
```

but I can't do this:

```
sudo ( whoami ; whoami )
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Run a shell inside `sudo`:
`sudo bash -c 'whoami; whoami'`

You can use any character except `'` itself inside the single quotes. If you really want to have a single quote in that command, use `'\''` (which technically is: end single-quote literal, literal `'` character, start single-quoted literal; but effectively this is a way to inject a single quote in a single-quoted literal string).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Not really if you know the trick — see my edit.

Comment: The trick does not scale well to multiple levels of quoting. Unlike multiple levels of here-documents.

Comment: I believe escaping within single quotes requires the `$''` syntax : `echo '\''` is considered as `echo <a string with just a backslash followed by a string that will continue on the next line>`, whereas `echo $'\''` shows `'`.

Comment: @AnthonyD. Inside `$'…'`, you can use `\'` to include a single quote. Inside `'…'`, you need `'\''` instead. It isn't parsed as an escape, but it behaves like one. `echo '\''` looks like an attempt to use `\'` as an escape inside single quotes, but it doesn't work that way, as I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 70):

You can pass the commands as standard input into sudo'ed bash with a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```
sudo bash <<"EOF"
whoami
id
EOF
```

This way there is no need to fiddle with correct quoting, especially if you have multiple levels, e.g.:

```
sudo bash <<"EOF"
whoami
echo $USER ~
sudo -u apache bash <<"DOF"
whoami
echo $USER ~
DOF
EOF
```

Produces:

```
root
root /root
apache
apache /usr/share/httpd
```

(Note that you can't indent the inner terminator — it has to be alone on its line. If you want to use indentation in a here document, you can use `<<-` instead of `<<`, but then you must indent with tabs, not spaces.)

Comment: Here documents (there's no pipe involved) are indeed more convenient for a long command, but you do need to take care about quoting. You need to quote the heredoc end marker after `<<`, otherwise the outer shell would perform `$` expansion. And if you nest, remember that the end marker has to be alone on its line, it can't be indented (unless you use the `<<-` form and indent with tabs). And of course using a here document for the script input precludes passing data as input to the script.

Comment: @Gilles You are right, the opening marker has to be quoted, see my updated answer.

Comment: Readers should note that it's `<<"EOF"` and not `<<EOF`, otherwise variables are expanded too early.

Answer (score 8):

If you would like to get syntax highlighting from your editor, not use quotes around your code, and have proper indentation, you can write your commands in a function and send it to bash using the `declare` command:

```
function run_as_root() {
    whoami
    id
    echo $USER
}

sudo bash -c "$(declare -f run_as_root); run_as_root"
```

Answer (score -2):

The Brackets means that execute the command in a new bash.It execute the command with the interval of semicolon.Just use the code below instead.

```
(sudo whoami;sudo whoami)
```

BYW:the space is not necessary when using '()'.

Answer (score -3):

sudo only asks for your passwd the first time.The passwd answered is valid for about 5 minutes by default.You can change this value as [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=183418) told.So just worry about the passwd prompt at the beginning of your script,then you can use **sudo** through out.
changing Defaults:user_name timestamp_timeout's value to -1 may be a security hole on your system.

Comment: What I mean is sudo only prompts for password at the first time.no prompt within 5 minutes or more.How long will your script run?exit with 5 minutes?You should never change the default value to -1.

Few cmds require root permission.just use sudo foo anywhere in your script at each line,or connected by comma.

Comment: alternatively you can configure defined list of commands and scripts for sudo without password. of course your scripts should be written with security good practices. you should prevent for using external attributes if it possible, because in bash are too many traps.