# How to set sudo in current shell mid-script without leaving current shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sudo

I would like to enable sudo within this bash function mid-script. I believe the issue is that `sudo -s` opens up a new shell, and all subsequent lines aren't printed because the shell is exited.

```
function example {
    echo "one"
    sudo -s
    echo "two"
    echo "three"
}
```

How can I have `two` and `three` also get printed as sudo? Without adding `sudo` before each?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run two commands in sudo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560442/how-to-run-two-commands-in-sudo) Also, an option using a heredoc is [at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435312/how-can-i-execute-a-series-of-commands-in-a-bash-subshell-as-another-user-using) which is a little prettier.

Answer (score 0):

What about a double function? Can that help?

```
#!/bin/bash 
function test2 {
sudo echo "two"
sudo echo "three"
}
function test {
echo "one"
test2
}
test
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your script test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
testfunc() {
echo "test";
sudo sh -c "echo 'haha'";
echo "hooo";
}
testfunc;
```

Then call it with:

> bash test.sh